# How can I pull Mail Contact groups for each contact with powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, contacts

I am trying to create a script to pull contact groups and put them in an excel sheet. Here is what I have so far:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=XXXXX,OU=XXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=DOM" -Filter * | foreach-object                                   {
write-host "User:" $_.Name -foreground green
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | foreach-object {
    write-host "Member Of:" $_.name
}
} | Export-Csv c:\tech.csv
```

This works for User accounts (except for the export for some reason), but not Contacts.

The script doesn't return anything for the distro groups of contacts when running it. We have a list of contacts that are part of distro groups that we, most likely, don't need anymore. I'm running this from a remote computer through powershell and I figured I could use this script and point it to the specific Contact OU.

I have also tried this from our Exchange servers:

```
Get-Contact | 
sort-object LastName | 
%{ Get-MailContact $_.DistinguishedName | select Name,Member,PrimarySMTPAddress }
```

There doesn't appear to be a "Members" property.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you edit some more detail into your post to elaborate on your problems?  For example, how did you try to perform this operation on Contacts, and how exactly does `Export-CSV` fail?  Is it erroneous, or does it not output what you expect?  These sort of details make questions easier to troubleshoot, and usually directs help to you sooner.

Comment: Hi thanks, the script doesn't return anything for the distro groups of contacts when running it. We have a list of contacts that are part of distro groups that we, most likely, don't need anymore. I'm running this from a remote computer through powershell and I figured I could use this script and point it to the specific Contact OU. I'm just learning powershell, so really new to it.

Comment: I have also tried this from our Exchange servers powershell:

Get-Contact | sort-object LastName | %{ Get-MailContact $_.DistinguishedName | select Name,Memb
er,PrimarySMTPAddress }

There doesn't appear to be a "Members" property

Answer (score 0):

try this.
Not optimal, but it works.

get-distributiongroup | foreach {write-host ---------- $*.samaccountname; get-distributiongroupmember -resultsize unlimited $*.samaccountname | where {$_.RecipientType -eq "mailcontact"} | ft name}